# How to set the player draw distance?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

How can I set the draw distance of players in the minecraft bedrock alpha server software?

I can set the view distance (landscape), the render distance (active chunks) but somehow I cannot set how far away players can walk from each other before they "despawn". Which is annoying, because you can see terraforming happening, without seeing the actual player doing that.

Comment: MCBE differentiates between "view distance" and "render distance"? Is this like loaded chunks (server-side) and visible chunks (client-side)? And what is that third thing you mean?

Comment: @FabianRöling Yes. Loaded chunks mean, the crops (for instance) will continue to grow. View distance is just "dead landscape" basically. But there is no option for "player distance". A player dissappears after like 10 chunks it seems.